# Cant populate dataset from database using ConsoleTV's chart package in laravel 5.5

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, charts, package

why i cant populate data set from my database? I can render the chart but there is no data shown. But when i use the "dd" command in laravel it shows me the array of the data. Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my output right now https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9OCU.jpg

Here is my Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


use Charts;
use App\Graph;

class GraphController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $chart = Charts::database(Graph::get()->find(1),'line','highcharts')
                 ->title('Tokens')
                 ->ElementLabel('Coins Sold')
                 ->Responsive(true)
                 ->data(Graph::all())

                ;

            //dd($chart);



          return view('coin.news', ['chart' => $chart]);



    }
}
```

My Graph.php Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Auth;
use Cache;
use Charts;


class Graph extends Model
{
    //

    protected $connection = 'mysql2';
    protected $table = 'ico_stages';



}
```

My graph.blade.php

```
@section('graph')

  {!! $chart->render() !!}

@endsection
```

My app.blade.php

```
Header files...


 {!! Charts::assets() !!}

Content....

Graph Section...

Footers....
```

web.php

```
//Landing Page
Route::get('/coin', 'GraphController@index');
```

Comment: answers anyone? please help.. badly need it

Answer (score 0):

Can you Try this one

```
return view('coin.news', ['chart' => $chart])->render();
```

Instead of

```
return view('coin.news', ['chart' => $chart]);
```

Comment: it gets me an error sir  ..
Call to undefined method App\Graph::filter()

Comment: is that an error to your model? Could you try this one `return view('coin.news', compact('chart'));`

Comment: still no data displayed sir.

Comment: still want to help?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
return view('coin.news', compact('chart'));
```

Comment: It gives me this error sir : Undefined variable: chart

Comment: can you share coin.news blade ? where you are trying to render html.

Comment: what do you mean sir?

Comment: As per your code you are sending data to news file that will render data to graph file so can you share news blade file?.

Comment: yes sir im sending the data to the news file and then i yield my graph there which is separated in graph.blade.php

Comment: still want to help sir?

Comment: Please explain what that code does, and why you think that it solves the problem. Simply stating "try this" does not help the OP to learn from your answer